# Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\\Support\\Manager::createDriver()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, lumen, laravel-middleware

I had a look at every post related to this error in Laravel:

[Missing argument 1 for Illuminate Support Manager - createDriver()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204959/missing-argument-1-for-illuminate-support-managercreatedriver-laravel-fcm)

[2th link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626656/missing-argument-1-for-illuminate-support-managercreatedriver-while-sending)

[3th link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332111/missing-argument-1-for-illuminate-support-managercreatedriver-while-using-lu)

None of them solved my issue: I am using Laravel Lumen version 5.4 and [Dingo API package](https://github.com/dingo/api).

I want to access to the Authenticated User in the incoming request:

```
 $request->user(); //returns an instance of the authenticated user
```

However this will throw me an error saying:

> Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), called in /var/www/html/myApp/vendor/illuminate/support/Manager.php on line 88 and defined",

I know that in order to  get the Authenticated User, you need to provide the Auth Middleware inside the routing:

```
  $api->get('register/{accountId}', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\RegisterController@registerAction']);
```

But adding the Middleware Auth inside my route will actually not reach the Controller endpoint and throw the same error that you can see above.

I have the AuthServiceProvider registered in my bootstrap/app.php:

```
 $app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
```

And this is the AuthServiceProvider class:

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Providers;

 use App\Models\Account;
 use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

 class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
  /**
   * Register any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function register() {
   }

  /**
   * Boot the authentication services for the application.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function boot() {
    // Here you may define how you wish users to be authenticated for your Lumen
    // application. The callback which receives the incoming request instance
    // should return either a User instance or null. You're free to obtain
    // the User instance via an API token or any other method necessary.

    $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {

        if ($request->input('api_token')) {
            return Account::where('api_token', $request->input('api_token'))->first();
        }
    });
   }
  }
```

This is what I have in config/auth.php:

```
  <?php

  return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
 ],

];
```

I tried to debug the issue myself and I found out that this is where it is breaking in Laravel:

```
/**
 * Create a new driver instance.
 *
 * @param  string  $driver
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
protected function createDriver($driver)
{
    // We'll check to see if a creator method exists for the given driver. If not we
    // will check for a custom driver creator, which allows developers to create
    // drivers using their own customized driver creator Closure to create it.
    if (isset($this->customCreators[$driver])) {
        return $this->callCustomCreator($driver);
    } else {
        $method = 'create'.Str::studly($driver).'Driver';

        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            return $this->$method();
        }
    }
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Driver [$driver] not supported.");
}
```

I can see in the stackTrace that it is passing a NULL driver inside createDriver() method which cause the error that I'm having. I wonder if it is not a simple configuration thing that I have to add inside my .env file.

I am starting with Laravel Lumen, it's a great tool for building API and I'm not blaming the tool itself (I took a lot of time reading the beautiful documentation), I'm pretty sure that I missed something very simple, if someone can guide me to this, I will be very pleased.

Comment: Did you uncomment the `$app->routeMiddleware()` call in `bootstrap/app.php`.

Comment: @PankitGami Yes I do have in bootstrap > app.php this line:  $app->routeMiddleware([
     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
 ]);

Comment: Is it commented or uncommented?

Comment: @PankitGami It is uncommented, the call to the routeMiddleware is available in the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout) (with [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) search driver)?

I came across the errors you seen while running my database seeds. In the end, I realized my tired mind forgot to define the correct env variables in my .env file, as below:

```
SCOUT_DRIVER=algolia
ALGOLIA_APP_ID=yourAlgoliaAppId
ALGOLIA_SECRET=yourAlgoliaSecret
```

If you haven't published the scout config file, do so with the following command:

> php artisan vendor:publish
>   --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"

Make sure you have put 'Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider::class' in the providers array in 'config/app.php' before running the above command.

Once I published the config file (named config/scout.php by default), I used the env variables as below:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Search Engine
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default search connection that gets used while
    | using Laravel Scout. This connection is used when syncing all models
    | to the search service. You should adjust this based on your needs.
    |
    | Supported: "algolia", "elasticsearch", "null"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SCOUT_DRIVER'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Index Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify a prefix that will be applied to all search index
    | names used by Scout. This prefix may be useful if you have multiple
    | "tenants" or applications sharing the same search infrastructure.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => env('SCOUT_PREFIX', ''),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Data Syncing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to control if the operations that sync your data
    | with your search engines are queued. When this is set to "true" then
    | all automatic data syncing will get queued for better performance.
    |
    */

    'queue' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Algolia Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your Algolia settings. Algolia is a cloud hosted
    | search engine which works great with Scout out of the box. Just plug
    | in your application ID and admin API key to get started searching.
    |
    */

    'algolia' => [
        'id' => env('ALGOLIA_APP_ID'),
        'secret' => env('ALGOLIA_SECRET'),
    ],

];
```

Once I did all of the above, the errors went away. This answer might not directly address your exact issue, but it could perhaps give you thoughts or aid your troubleshooting process.